# Run php script through cron hangs the terminal

Tags: php, cron

I have a php script that will run via cron

```
*/5 * * * * /var/www/scripts/run.php
```

run.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
#stop server
exec("python /home/server.py stop");

#execute some php code here

#start server again
exec("python server.py start 2>&1 &");
?>
```

The last line causes the problem.

When I run the php script directly from the terminal

```
/var/www/scripts/run.php
```

It starts the server but the terminal hangs

When the script is run through cron

I see in ps the below ven though the script is done

```
root     23510  0.5  1.3 280064 14228 ?        Ss   10:32   0:00 /usr/bin/php /var/www/scripts/run.php
```

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You can't call python from inside PHP like that can you? Shouldn't you be executing python through exec or system?

Comment: and remeber to specify full path

Comment: Looks like you don't really need php here, but a bash script would do. Also, you SHOULD NOT keep it in `www`. Move it to a directory not visible to the web.

Comment: @davidethell Modified the code to reflect my exact script

Answer (score 1):

If your PHP script is really a shell script, change the shebang. If you want the python calls to run in the background, append "&" at the end of the line. If you make it a shell script, try executing it with `sh -x <script>` to see which command hangs.

If you want to make it a valid PHP script, it is going to be a lot of work, but if you're using POSIX, you can use fork() which will make it relatively simple.

Comment: Hi. No I do not need a UNIX shell script but a valid php one. Also, I use linux. Can you provide some example with fork? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your last line to this:

```
exec("nohup python server.py start 2>&1 &");
```

The nohup will tell the process not to stop when the controlling process or user is gone. That may or may not be your issue, but worth a try.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it but the result is the same.

Comment: What if you redirect your output to a file? Try changing the end to ">> some_output_file &"

Comment: Still nothing. It is driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

Finally the code that does the trick

```
exec("nohup python server.py start &> /dev/null &");
```